# Button with JS handler does not submit form

Tags: javascript, html

I recently started getting into HTML & Javascript and I think both are very fascinating languages. I have however encountered an error, which I cannot resolve, on my journey.

Basically what I'm doing is trying to create a login form, and I cannot get it to submit.

Button (login.html):

```
<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="verifyLogin()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
```

Include JS script (login.html):

```
<script src="../js/login.js"></script>
```

JavaScript (login.js):

```
$(function() {
    var $formLogin = $('#login-form');
    var $formLost = $('#lost-form');
    var $formRegister = $('#register-form');
    var $divForms = $('#div-forms');
    var $modalAnimateTime = 300;
    var $msgAnimateTime = 150;
    var $msgShowTime = 2000;

    $("form").submit(function () {
        switch(this.id) {
            case "login-form":
                var $lg_username=$('#login_username').val();
                var $lg_password=$('#login_password').val();
                if ($lg_username == "ERROR") {
                    msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Login error");
                } else {
                    msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Login OK");
                }
                return false;
                break;
            case "lost-form":
                var $ls_email=$('#lost_email').val();
                if ($ls_email == "ERROR") {
                    msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Send error");
                } else {
                    msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Send OK");
                }
                return false;
                break;
            case "register-form":
                var $rg_username=$('#register_username').val();
                var $rg_email=$('#register_email').val();
                var $rg_password=$('#register_password').val();
                if ($rg_username == "ERROR") {
                    msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Register error");
                } else {
                    msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Register OK");
                }
                return false;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#login_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formRegister) });
    $('#register_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLogin); });
    $('#login_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formLost); });
    $('#lost_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formLogin); });
    $('#lost_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formRegister); });
    $('#register_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLost); });

    function verifyLogin($email, $password){
        if($email === "admin" && $password === "1234"){
            alert("Login succesful");
        } else {
            alert("Could not login");
        }
    }

    function modalAnimate ($oldForm, $newForm) {
        var $oldH = $oldForm.height();
        var $newH = $newForm.height();
        $divForms.css("height",$oldH);
        $oldForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime, function(){
            $divForms.animate({height: $newH}, $modalAnimateTime, function(){
                $newForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime);
            });
        });
    }

    function msgFade ($msgId, $msgText) {
        $msgId.fadeOut($msgAnimateTime, function() {
            $(this).text($msgText).fadeIn($msgAnimateTime);
        });
    }

    function msgChange($divTag, $iconTag, $textTag, $divClass, $iconClass, $msgText) {
        var $msgOld = $divTag.text();
        msgFade($textTag, $msgText);
        $divTag.addClass($divClass);
        $iconTag.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
        $iconTag.addClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
        setTimeout(function() {
            msgFade($textTag, $msgOld);
            $divTag.removeClass($divClass);
            $iconTag.addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
            $iconTag.removeClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
        }, $msgShowTime);
    }
});
```

I'm aware that the function does nothing at the moment. I just don't know what's wrong.

Best Regards,

Comment: Please read [ask]. One of the most important parts of a question is the title, and yours says nothing about the content of your question.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Just visually inspecting your code, the issue I can see is that verifyLogin takes 2 parameters, and when you are calling it (via onclick), you are passing in non.

Comment: @NicolaiArpe I opened this question because the title looked like something that needed to be closed, but the body has much more information than the title conveys. If my edit wasn't correct (or you just don't like it), feel free to roll it back or make more changes, but please use a better title.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and don't know much about the site =) Fully correct. Thanks!

Comment: does your form have an action. Is your button within a form?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: verifyLogin is not defined. My button is indeed within a form.

Comment: I don't think that `boolean` belongs there. Shouldn't that just be `var`? Javascript isn't statically typed.

Comment: Yeah I figured that part out haha. Not sure what causes the other error though.

Comment: On a similar note, `(email && password).equal` isn't valid, is it? boolean types don't have an equals method. And even if it did have an equals method, what would `(email && password).equals("admin")` achieve anyhow? "if true equals admin"?

Comment: Move the <script> tag into the <head> element of your page. https://jsfiddle.net/h6v26xp8/

Comment: I think you should just replace the function body with `console.log('hello world');` and see if it works then. I think you have multiple errors in your function body.

Comment: Guys. I know that the code is not entirely correct. I'm just wondering why it tells me that my function isn't being found and not some other error related to the insides of the function =)

Comment: @DavidS same error :/

Comment: ... If there are errors in the function, then the function may not be defined. Another StackOverflow tip: don't post a question and ask experts to ignore the errors because you're "sure" it's not causing the problem.

Comment: I would try using the full path to login.js to make sure it's finding that file.

Comment: Thanks! Will do in the future.
@bmb I am sure that it is finding the file because I'm using other methods from the file in my code.

Comment: @DavidS For JavaScript in the browser, function's aren't executed until called, so any errors inside them wouldn't cause the function to not be defined. If there is an error *external* to the function definition, that would cause the interpreter to halt, and the function to be undefined.

Comment: @nicarpe Can you post the entire `login.js` file? If that file is being loaded, but the `verifyLogin` function isn't defined, then one of two things is happening: 


1. That file has an error before verifyLogin is defined
2. The file is being included in a manner that the function is not defined when the DOM is built.

Comment: @Alan, I know what you mean, but for Chrome at least the syntax errors in `verifyLogin` prevent it from ever being defined. I've confirmed this with a very simple HTML file: open it in Chrome and you get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on the `boolean`. Then press the Login button and get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: verifyLogin is not defined`.

Comment: Added it to OP @Alan

Answer (score 3):

You have many errors in your code, you have to double check your source of learning. first off a working code:

```
<script>
console.log("hi");
function verifyLogin($email, $password){
    var isValid = false;
    if($email === "admin" && $password === "admin"){
        alert("just logged in!");
        isValid = true;
    }
}
</script>

<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="verifyLogin('admin', 'admin')" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
```

1) this line:

```
boolean isValid = false;
```

makes no sense in javascript. boolean is simply a javascript data type, the syntax you are looking for is

```
var
```

which by itself is a reference to a spot in memory, that spot can contain a boolean, which is data type.

2) your javascript code should be above the html as javascript is synchronous

3) all this line is just plain wrong:

```
if((email && password).equals("admin")){
```

you didn't define equals, and the syntax you are using will not work. please, drop whatever source you are trying to learn and learn from:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for me to use this piece of code in another file? I've tried including it, but it doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: The reason I didn't check the code through or attempt to fix it was because I encountered another error (I was unable to get it working in my login.js file). I am a Java coder by the way.

Comment: If you are trying to use this code in a html file, it will work fine.